# How to import behavior in choregraphe

Tags: nao-robot, choregraphe

When I try to import behavior from another project into my current project the following error occurs:

[image: Choregraphe import behavior error]

I Have also tried to copy and paste the behavior directly into the project's folder, but it is not visible in the project's tree.

So I wonder what is the right way to import behavior from other projects?
And what am I doing wrong to get this error message or it is choregraphe problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are doing it right, and that Choregraphe encounters an issue reading your files. Make sure that you did not open elsewhere any of the files of the behavior, because Windows may prevent some file operations in this case.

You can instead "import folder..." and make sure the behaviors are cleanly advertised in the package by checking that they are checked in the properties of your project.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the "import behavior" feature is currently broken. I got the following log when doing it: "Import behavior error: destination is empty".

But when copying a behavior in your project folder it should be added or not depending on your preferences. By default a popup appears to ask you if you want to add the new files to the project. You can change this behavior in "Edit/Preferences: Upon external modification".

By the way a behavior file should always be named behavior.xar.